# How can I list all of the sites on my CARTO map on the side of the map for easy access?

Tags: carto

I have created a [map in CARTO](http://alyd.carto.com/builder/285c87d5-241b-4759-a12b-b034cdda73e2/embed?state=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22ne%22%3A%5B38.25311480863329%2C-122.54795073182325%5D%2C%22sw%22%3A%5B38.35697343069593%2C-122.39362715394239%5D%2C%22center%22%3A%5B38.30506270807554%2C-122.47078894288282%5D%2C%22zoom%22%3A13%7D%7D) that I would like to have all of the different sites in a list on the side of the map (similar to what the current widget does, but with more than 5 sites, and ideally zooming to each when clicked). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **CARTO Builder category widgets are limited to 5 categories and the zooming behavior is not supported**. But, you could build a customer webmap application with those requirements using [CARTO.js](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/) or [CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/) (webmap rendering libraries) in combination with [Airship](https://carto.com/developers/airship/) (design framework).